# Flow map with QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, flow-map

I've used QGIS for many years and made great flow maps.

But within QGIS 3 I can't find any flow making plugin like the ones in QGIS 2.X versions.

Do you know how to do?

Comment: The plugins for QGIS 2 do not work in QGIS 3. If a plugin is available in QGIS 3 depends on it's authors willingness to rewrite the plugins. At any time you have the option to rewrite the plugin yourself (it is open source!), hire someone who does it for you or contact the author.

Answer (score 1):

All QGIS plugins will have bug report and issue tracking pages.

I would post an issue on the specific plugins issue tracker to see if they are converting it to QGIS 3.

If not you could try converting it yourself. It is not a difficult process.

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/wiki/Plugin-migration-to-QGIS-3

https://gisforthought.com/updating-a-plugin-from-qgis-2-to-qgis-3/

Comment: However, what about the privacy of the plugin that was created by another developer? Does the migration inherit the original copyright?

Comment: It does. All QGIS plugins are at least GPL2 so you can copy and modify them no problem as long as if you publish it you also publish the source code.

Comment: thank you. I am not that advanced in migration, nevertheless your website makes it explicit. I should give a try. Thanks for a source